# About two axiomatization style of first order logic.

Tags: logic

Dear members of StackExchange.

Reading some basic book in logic I see there are (at least) two thinking school about  axiomatization of first order theories.

I consider  D.J.Monk book "Mathematical logic"  (Gradute text in Math n.37), and Herbert Enderton "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic".

We have two axiomatization of deduction:

$T\vdash p$  (Monk, p.171)
and $T\vdash' p$   (Enderton pag. 112).

Brielfly, about "$\vdash $"  we allow generalization rule:

if:  $T\vdash p(x)$  then $T\vdash \forall x p(x)$

and  a weak deduction theorem (Monk pag 188):

If $T\cup\{p\} \vdash q$ then $T \vdash p\to q$ ,  *under the condition that*   $p$ is  sentence (no free variables).

About "$\vdash'$ " (Enderton) dont allow a generalization rule as above (can generalize  any logic axioms, see Enderton pag.112, and we have a theorem that "allow" a generalization under some hypothesis (Enderton p.117 )), and ut has a strong deduction theorem (Enderton, pag 118-19):

If $T\cup\{p\} \vdash q$ then $T \vdash p\to q$  (any formula $p$).

All right, both sytems prevent from the wrong deduction:

$\top\ \vdash\   p(x)\to\forall x:p(x)$.

At least if we work in syntactical way.

BUT, by theorem of completeness (Monk, 11.20 pag.204 ; Enderton pag.135):

$T\vdash p$ iff   $T\models p$  iff   $T\vdash' p$  (each formula $p$)

then we have  $T\vdash p\ $ iff  $\ T\vdash' p$ and this is weird, infact
if that is true, from

$\top \wedge p(x) \vdash  p(x)$   (tautological)

follow by generalization rule:

$\top \wedge p(x) \vdash  \forall p(x)$

then by deduction:

$\top  \vdash\  p(x)\to\forall p(x)$  (wrong!)

Do we have two semantic relation $T\models p$  and   $T\models' p$ related to

syntactical $T\vdash  p\ $, $\ T\vdash'  p$ ?

Can you help me to understand my mistake?

Best regard.

Buschi Sergio.

Comment: All completeness implies is that $\models$ can prove anything $\models'$ can. What you've done is used the rules of both systems simultaneously, therefore effectively creating a new system which is a combination of those two. Nothing guarantees that this new system is consistent and, in fact, you've shown that it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are two different notions of $\models$ here, matching the two versions of $\vdash$. The difference is in the meaning of $\Gamma\models\Sigma$ when $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ can contain free variables. One meaning is "For every structure and every assignment of values to variables, if all formulas in $\Gamma$ are true, then so are all formulas in $\Sigma$." The other meaning is "For all structures, if all assignments of values to variables make $\Gamma$ true, then all assignments of values to variables make $\Sigma$ true." The difference is that, in the first meaning, the universal quantifier "all assignments of values to variables" applies to the implication from "$\Gamma$ true" to "$\Sigma$ true", whereas in the second meaning, the same quantifier is applied to the $\Gamma$ part and the $\Sigma$ part individually.  And that makes the meanings different.

An easy example, with a predicate symbol $P$ and two variables $x,y$ is $P(x)\models P(y)$. This is false under the first meaning but true under the second.

Comment: Very insightful.
However in both mentioned texts (and all texts I see) they use the same definition for the "logically entails"  and it is according to the "first meaning" defined by you.

However, it is clear that a presentation of first-order logic that has:

1) the deduction theorem in strong form (as Enderton, or Barnes, Mack ).

2) p(x) |= forall x p(x) .

3) completeness theorem

Is wrong, infact from (3): p(x) |- forall x p(x) ; from (1):  True |-   p(x)- > forall x p(x).

I seem the the (2) is valid both in your first meaning, than in the second one.

Comment: With the first meaning, $P(x)\models P(y)$ is false. Consider a structure whose underlying set is $\{0,1\}$ and with $P$ interpreted as being true of $0$ and false of $1$. Then the assignment giving $x$ the value $0$ and giving $y$ the value $1$ makes $P(x)$ true and $P(y)$ false. So it also makes $\forall x\,P(x)$ false. Thus, this is a counterexample to both $P(x)\models P(y)$ and $P(x)\models\forall x\,P(x)$.